# Reporting using NUnit

Tags: xml, vb.net, nunit

I want to have a managerial report after executing tests from NUnit. By looking into NUnit, It seems as it generates the output in XML format. Plz any one can give suggesttion of how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) to transform your xml in to something more pretty.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the tools provided on the NUnit web site: NUnitResults or NUnit-Summary. I haven't tried either of them but that's where I would start.

You might also want to consider running your unit tests as part of an automated build using CruiseControl.NET. CruiseControl produces quite useful summary reports for each build, reporting the number of tests run, the number of failures, the time it took, plus details for all failures.